# php with Prestashop 1.7 : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Db' not found in

Tags: php, sql, prestashop

Simple PHP code to run an SQL query from web browser.

```
    <?php

$insertData = array(
         'id_product'  => 122, 
         'id_carrier_reference'  => 8, 
         'id_shop'   => 1,
      );

$table = "product_carrier" ;

if (!Db::getInstance()->insert($table, $insertData))
     die('erreur!');
```

I get this error **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Db' not found in...**

I put the small script in a php file : test.php, in the web server root 
and run http://mywebsite.com/test.php

What is wrong exactly ?

Comment: It doesn't find the Db class. You should include it first.

Comment: hi, thanks for the comment.
I tried that as well as below, but still the same. Do I need to include other classes ?
`<?php
require './classes/db/Db.php';
$insertData = array(
         'id_product'  => 122, 
         'id_carrier_reference'  => 8, 
         'id_shop'   => 1,
      );
$table = "product_carrier" ;
if (!Db::getInstance()->insert($table, $insertData))
  die('erreur!');`

>> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Db' not found in /home/prestashop/docroot/AdminImportController.php:

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate PrestaShop. If you are running this script in the root PrestaShop folder, include this line at the beginning of the file:

`require dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php';`